# Connect error: simple socket programming in C in Ubuntu

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu

I've got an example socket program from my teacher -- *get the datetime from the server*.However, I can not run this program well. I run the server on a terminal, then run the client on another terminal(use "./client 127.0.0.1"), then I get a "**connect error**". I have replaced the "print" to "perror", Then I get an error message: "**Connection refused**".

I don't know what's wrong with this. Can you help me fix the problem?
You can modify my code to make it run, then paste it here. I just want to **get the current time from the server**.

My code is here:

datetime.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096
```

datetimes.c:

```
/****************************************************/
/************* datetime Example Server **************/
/****************************************************/
#include "datetime.h"
#include <sys/time.h>

int
main( int argc , char * * argv )
{
    int listenfd , connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[ MAXLINE ];
    time_t ticks;

    listenfd = socket( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );

    memset( &servaddr , 0 , sizeof( servaddr ) );
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( 13 );

    bind( listenfd , (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr , sizeof( servaddr ) );
    listen( listenfd , 1024 );

    for( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Before Accept...\n");
        connfd = accept( listenfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL );
        ticks = time( NULL );
        snprintf( buff , sizeof( buff ) , "%.24s\r\n" , ctime( &ticks ) );
        write( connfd , buff , strlen( buff ) );
        close( connfd );
    }
}
```

datetimec.c:

```
/****************************************************/
/************* datetime Example Client **************/
/****************************************************/

#include "datetime.h"

int main( int argc , char * * argv )
{
    int sockfd , n ;
    char recvline[ MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if( argc != 2 )  {
        printf( "usage : a.out <IP address>\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if( ( sockfd = socket( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 ) ) < 0 ) {
        printf( "socket error\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    memset( &servaddr , 0 , sizeof( servaddr ) );
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( 13 );

    if( inet_pton( AF_INET , argv[ 1 ] , &servaddr.sin_addr ) <= 0 )  {
        printf( "inet_pton error for %s\n" , argv[ 1 ] );
        exit( 1 ); 
    }

    if( connect( sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr , sizeof( servaddr ) ) < 0 )  {
        printf( "connect error\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    while( ( n = read( sockfd , recvline , MAXLINE ) ) > 0 )  {
        recvline[ n ] = 0;
        if( fputs( recvline , stdout ) == EOF ) {
            printf( "fputs error\n" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
    }

    if( n < 0 )  {
        printf( "read error\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    exit( 0 );  
}
```

Comment: Use `perror` rather than printf to get the actual error message.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `print` to `perror`, now I get the error message: `Connection refused`. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Good. Now check the return values of all the system calls in the server too, and use perror when they fail.

Comment: On Linux, you need root privileges (sudo), to create a port < 1025; also you shouldn't bind on 13 and then connect from 13.

Comment: The server is always waiting, and I have no chance to check the return value. `connfd = accept( listenfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL );` There must be a while loop in the "accept" function.

Comment: @metadings I've tried sudo, and the problem still there. I also tried to modify the port number in "datetimec.c", no difference. And, are you sure that the port number in "datetimec.c" is for "connect from", not "connect to"?

Comment: @WoodMan you're right, it's "connect to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the port number (currently: `13`) in both client and server:

```
servaddr.sin_port = htons( 13 );
```

to a value higher than 1024 because **the first 1024 porst are reserved for root access and many of them are already used by some services** (actually, 13 is a port number of [daytime protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol)).

I believe your proffesor wants you to just get datetime from the server, **not** use the datetime protocol.

However, your code gives a SEGFAULT when ports are corrected, because of this line:

```
snprintf( buff , sizeof( buff ) , "%.24s\r\n" , ctime( &ticks ) );
```

To fix it:

1. Use `strncpy()` instead, i.e. change that line to: `strncpy(buff, ctime(&ticks), MAXLINE);`
2. Use `ctime()` function from the proper header file: change `<sys/time.h>` to `<time.h>` in you includes.

Comment: I get a SEGFAULT too. Then, how to fix that line? Can you give me further instruction?

Comment: I have explained in my answer how you should fix it.

Comment: Finally, I've got it down. Your answer is really useful. @REACHUS